# Python string strip function

Tags: python

Why are following code can remove '+':

```
a = '+'
a.strip('+')
#output: ''

a = '1+'
a.strip('+')
#output: '1'

a = '+66'
a.strip('+')
#output: '66'
```

But the followings can't:

```
a = '1+2'
a.strip('+')
#output: '1+2'
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The `strip()` function only removes leading and trailing characters - on the outside of the string. Since in your last example the `+` is in the middle, it doesn't remove it. Maybe try using `replace()` instead:

```
my_str = "1+2"
new_str = my_str.replace("+", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip` only removes the specified heading and trailing characters the string, not in the middle.

Similarly, `rstrip` only removes the trailing ones.